# Cached Autocomplete oncomplete

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I am using primefaces autocomplete with attribute cache=true.
When I get a cached response from autocomplete the "oncomplete" event will not be triggered because no ajax request is sent.
Is there any possibility to trigger if autocomplete returned a value?
BR

```
<p:autoComplete id="#{cc.attrs.id}"
            styleClass="#{cc.attrs.styleClass}" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
            minQueryLength="#{cc.attrs.minQueryLength}"
            maxResults="#{cc.attrs.maxResults}"
            completeMethod="#{geoCodingBacking.findAddress}"
            placeholder="#{cc.attrs.placeholder}" cache="true"
            queryDelay="#{cc.attrs.queryDelay}"
            forceSelection="#{cc.attrs.forceSelection}" 
            >
            <p:ajax event="query"
                onstart="startLoading()"
                oncomplete="endLoading()" />
        </p:autoComplete>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a listener for the itemSelect event:

```
<p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.onItemSelect}"/>
```

Comment: But the "itemSelect" event is triggered when a user clicked on a item from a list. I want to have an event when autocomplete successful autocompleted therefore autocomplete provides a list of suggestions

Comment: When you said autocomplete returned a value I thought you meant an item selection, not your query results. You want to have `onstart` and `oncomplete` javascript called when you query your objects in `autocomplete` correct?

Comment: yes - but in case you set "cached=true" and autocomplete returns a cached object, oncomplete will not be triggered because no ajax request is sent.